# Reset ImageButton ImageUrl to default URL

Tags: c#, repeater, imagebutton, imageurl

I've an ImageButton into a Repeater.

My ASP.NET code is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="img_sport" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("IDSport") %>' CommandArgument='<%#  Eval("SportName") %>' ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("SportName","~/Images/{0}-trp.png") %>' OnCommand="img_sport_Click" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

From code behind I change the ImageUrl of selected/clicked image in this way:

```
[...]
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;
btn.ImageUrl = "/Images/" + sportName + "-trp-selected.png";
[...]
```

But, if I click on other images, I'll have two/three/four image shown as selected, so first of all, in my code behind, I would like to reset ImageUrl to default value, then I'll apply the new ImageUrl only to the selected/clicked ImageButton.

So, how can I reset all ImageUrl?

Answer (score 1):

On Seeing your code, I guess you want to change the image when it is clicked so that user can identify that whether image is selected or not. If you want to achieve this, why don't you try `JavaScript` which can handle same thing without postback.

See below code sample with JavaScript function for the same:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="img_sport" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("SportName","~/Images/{0}-trp.png") %>' OnClientClick='<%# "return ManageSelection(this,\"" + Eval("SportName").ToString() + "\");"%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ManageSelection(control, sportName) {
        var selectedImage = '/Images/' + sportName + "-trp-selected.png";
        $(control).attr('src', selectedImage);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```